# The Software Update tool shows already installed updates

Tags: macos, updates, software-update

The Software Update tool shows already installed updates. I already installed them a few times, clicking either the 'Update All' button or the individual 'Update' buttons. The apps are: Keynote, Numbers, Pages, Skitch, Evernote, Fotor. 'Check for unfinished downloads' reports all downloads have finished. Signing out and back in and reloading didn't help.

```
$ sudo softwareupdate -ia
Password:
Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2012 Apple Inc.

Finding available software
No updates are available.
```

Googling didn't help. How can I fix the GUI tool so it updates its status?

OSX 10.9.3